# beyond Compare not creating html report on Linux (Debian)

Tags: python, openshift, beyondcompare

I am deploying a Python Flask app on Openshift Platform by creating a Docker File.

Now my app is up and running fine but there is a feature where I have to use Beyond Compare for comparing 2 .txt file and generate a report in .html format.

The app is running fine on a Windows Server and generating all html reports and everything.

Now when I am trying to run the same Python script it is not creating the html report file.

Below is the Python command I am executing.

`subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/bcompare", '@"/project/ByndCmpResults/myscript.txt"' ,file1, file2, report_filename], shell=True)`

file1, file2 and report_filename are correctly defined.

Below is the content of myscript.txt

```
    options:display-all&
    output-to:"%3" &
    output-options:wrap-word,html-color "%1" "%2"
```

Below is the snap when I am running above command.

[image]

Requesting you to please help with the issue as I have been stuck with this since last week.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare on Linux requires an X-Window session to run, even when scripted. It will not run as a console application. Removing the X-Window session requirement is on the feature request list for a future version, but there isn't a workaround in the current version.

Comment: hey Chris, 
thanks for responding.
Can you please elaborate a little about X-Window session on ubuntu, i have been doing google but didnt got success.
I am deploying  my Python Flask app on OpenShift using Docker Ubuntu 18.04 as base image what i can do to set up the X-window session.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Beyond Compare on Linux has only been tested running with a GUI login while physically present at the Linux machine. It hasn't been tested running in containers, and I don't know if Linux containers support GUI apps.